# At what point would a piece of educational software become classed as gambling software?

Tags: united-kingdom, software, gambling

I am a Maths teacher and have had a thought about writing a web-based piece of software to simulate a horse race and the students could compete with one another by 'betting' on these horses. The software itself would not have any kind of stake/payout system, just award points based on outcomes.

If I was to make this software publicly available on the web, would I run the risk of being caught up in legal issues relating to betting or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be amazed if there were any legal issues, hundreds of online games would be illegal!